# What is the significance of comma in array and structure initialization?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, structure

While browsing through some codes, i came across this method of initialization:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct trial{
    int x, y;
};

int main(){
    int a[10] = {0,1, };//comma here
    struct trial z = {1, };//comma here
    return 0;
}
```

What is the significance of this comma operator? I do not find any difference in the method of initialization if the comma operator is removed.

Comment: This has been asked, and it's easier for tools to deal with or to add to later (see also enums).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense if you generate such code from scripts. It keeps your script simple. No edge-cases. In particular, you don't bother whether you need to add a `,` first, before writing one more item; you just write one item followed by a comma and you're done!

You don't care about the first item or last item. All items are *same* if there is a trailing comma.

Think from code-generation point of view. It would start making sense.

See this python script that generates such code:

```
print ("int a[] = {")
for item in items:
    print (item + ",")
print ("};")
```

It is simple. Now try writing a code without trailing comma. It wouldn't be *that* simple.

The standard also allows trailing-comma in enum definition:

```
enum A
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z, //last item : comman is okay
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Additionaly, allowing the comma at the last enum value is very handy if you #ifdef out some elements depending on configuration. If my memory serves, it became allowed in C with the 1999 standard.