# Would extra comma cause any difference in the array initializer in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-c++

To initialize an array partially, below 2 initializers look similar. Is there some difference under some condition? I assumed the first syntax would initialize all elements in the array as 1, but it is proved not to be the case.

```
int arr[2] = {1,};
int arr[2] = {1};
```

Another thought is the extra comma adds extra element to the array, like array size is 2 below. But this is also not the case.

```
int arr[] = {1,}; // sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) is 1 instead of 2
```

I am wondering is there any specific usage of the extra comma in the above initializer.

Comment: Explore before you ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160469/what-is-the-significance-of-comma-in-array-and-structure-initialization  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason